# extjs numberfield maxlength not working

Tags: extjs, extjs6, maxlength

I am new with Sencha Extjs 6. I want to use xtype:'numberfield' and it's working fine. But I want to set its max length, for example by 2, when input more than 2 digits just keep it nothing change. I don't know how to do it.

Please help me!!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to learn how to use [Sencha Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/api/Ext.form.field.Number.html).

Well for this you need to use `enforceMaxLength : true,` and `maxLength :2,`This will work as you want. I created a fiddle for you. [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1h6s) Please test

Comment: In your code, input value still can be more than 2 digits.

Comment: But if edit code to  enforceMaxLength : true, maxLength: 2 it works fine. When i applied it to my project it still not working. I dont know why.

Comment: After modified, your code works fine. But it's not working with my project. Is it because of Classic or Modern?? I am using Modern.
Below is my code:
xtype : 'numberfield',
flex : 1,
padding: '0 0 0 3px',
itemId:'date',
reference:'date',
autoComplete: false,
autoCorrect: false,
clearIcon: false,
required: true,
allowBlank:false,
maxLength: 2,
enforceMaxLength : true,

Comment: Apparently code is not loading in fiddler for modern.  Will try to get to load code by some other way.

Comment: @UDID It doesn't load because the application has to be called differently, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Alexander ya you may correct, I have to look because did'nt work much on modern.